# How to Full Control (Read/Write) of custom resource resw file (Universal Windows)

Tags: uwp, raspberry-pi3, uwp-xaml, windows-10-iot-core, resource-file

How can I read/write Keys/Values on a custom Resource File (resw) (storing string and conditional resources) ?

I added  Resource File(resw) for storing settings of app. And Then ?

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ResourceContext resourceContext = ResourceContext.GetForViewIndependentUse();
        ResourceMap resourceMap = ResourceManager.Current.MainResourceMap.GetSubtree("Resources");//resources.resw accessing in root is ok.
        var resourceValue = resourceMap.GetValue("PicPath", resourceContext);

        resourceMap.SetValue("DBPath", resourceContext,"PicPath2");//no write avaible ? ERROR LINE
    }
```

Comment: Settings?  You use ResourceLoader, it is well described in the [MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh694557.aspx).

Comment: no setvalue avaible ? are resouce files readonly?

Comment: what is the difference of this couple of lines ?:
ResourceContext resourceContext = ResourceContext.GetForViewIndependentUse();
and 

ResourceContext resourceContext =new ResourceContext();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To store read / write app values, you should use the [`ApplicationData` API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.Storage.ApplicationData). You can have local and / or roaming settings.

Resources are read-only and are for things like UI strings, images, etc. that you load at runtime and might want to change based on things like the user's language, the accessibility settings, the display's scale factor, etc.

Answer (score 1):

ResourceMap class does not have ***SetValue*** method. The *.resw files may contain only strings and file paths.At run time, the Windows.ApplicationModel.Resources.ResourceLoader class and the types in the Windows.ApplicationModel.Resources.Core namespace provide access to app resources, but does not provide write APIs.