# How to create localized resource files from excel? In UWP

Tags: uwp, uwp-xaml, localized

Let's say I have an excel file with String Labels in one column and different language content in different columns ( one column for each language).

Is there any efficient way to generate the resw files for different languages?

I had earlier written a script myself to generate the resw files but is there any automated way to generate the resource files In UWP ?

[A bit more context, I have been given a set of translated texts, I will have to create resw files for them each using them]

Thank you for reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> > How to create localized resource files from excel? In UWP

Derive from this [case reply](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47236868/how-to-full-control-read-write-of-custom-resource-resw-file-universal-windows) and [`ResourceLoader`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.applicationmodel.resources.resourceloader) api, the resource is read only that you could only edit it with Visual Studio.

> Is there any efficient way to generate the resw files for different languages?

If you could generate a new resw file, for different languages you could use `Multilingual App Toolkit` to create.

[image]

Comment: Can I write into a resource file from visual studio? actually, I have been given a set of translated texts,  I will have to create resw files for them each.

Comment: You could generate other languages with `Multilingual App Toolkit`. then modify different part.

Comment: And Visual studio has not provided enter point to import text. Currently, you could not edit it manually.